# make python print stacktrace when running on local host?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sockets

I have 3 python programs, the first 2 programs are ran with

```
python program1.py --bind localhost --port 8000
python program1.py --bind localhost --port 8080
```

The third program is ran with

```
python program3.py http://localhost:8000 http://localhost:8080
```

The exception is here:

```
try:
    result = getattr(self.agents[agent], fn) \
                        (*args + (self.credits[agent],))
    except socket.timeout:
        self.credits[agent] = -1.0  # ensure it is counted as expired
        raise TimeCreditExpired
    except (socket.error, xmlrpc.client.Fault) as e:
        logging.error("Agent %d was unable to play step %d." +
               " Reason: %s", agent, self.step, e)
```

Output when I press CTRL+C on program1:

```
program1:
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2021 23:28:43] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

program3:
2021-11-10 23:28:43,296 -- ERROR: Agent 1 was unable to play step 2. Reason: <Fault 1: "<class 'KeyboardInterrupt'"
```

but how can I get the stacktrace?

Thanks

Comment: The obvious solution is to call `logging.exception()` instead.

Comment: but that prints the exception on the server (program3)? I'd like to get the stacktrace of program1

Comment: Wait, so you want the program which crashed to send its traceback over the socket to the program which it failed to communicate with? That ... sounds challenging.

Comment: well not really, as long as the crash is displayed somewhere it's fine